# Best texts on supermathematics for a mathematician?

Tags: book-recommendation, noncommutative-algebra, superalgebra

I'm an undergraduate who's doing some summer mathematics research, and it looks like I need some information on Berezenians and supermatrices as well as supermathematics in general.

The only text I can find is for applications in statistical physics which I enjoy for my own purposes but doesn't sound too fruitful for my research. Any recommendations for books that are more math oriented would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Alec, I am curious where are you conducting summer research? Thanks.

Comment: The school I'm working for is in California, but I'll be living at home and researching this summer.

Comment: Quantum Fields and Strings: A course for Mathematicians. This is not a recommendation... not because it isn't good, but because I am not competent to judge... On the other hand, buyer beware - it is certainly "high powered mathematicians talking to high powered mathematicians" . It will be tough without (or with!) a graduate degree.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Peter, however it was a bit too broad for my purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to be gauche, but I ended up finding a good answer to my own question: Varadarajan's *[Supersymmetry for Mathematicians: An Introduction](http://alpha.sinp.msu.ru/~panov/LibBooks/SUSY/(Courant_Lecture_Notes_11)V._S._Varadarajan-Supersymmetry_for_Mathematicians__An_Introduction_(Courant_Lecture_Notes)-American_Mathematical_Society(2004).pdf)*

Answer (score 0):

Try "God created the integers" which is also commented by Stephen Hawkings.

http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2096.God_Created_The_Integers

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation, however this doesn't cover the parts of supersymmetry that I needed.